# Is the ReportViewer web control acceptable for an enterprise web application

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have been experimenting with the ReportViewer control in a webforms applications which is running reports remotely through a Report Server. It feels like the Parameter interface in the ReportViewer is limiting. I think another alternative is to create my own web form controls which pass parameters to the ReportViewer and bypass the default parameter interface. My experience with SSRS is very minimal and I'm wondering if this is a viable solution, or is it asking for trouble. (ie new reports could result in having to create new UI's). I guess my question is whether or not the standard user interface in the report viewer is acceptable for enterprise level applications. I'm not talking about the paging controls, more about the drop down lists and check box lists.

Answer (score 3):

If your reports typically use simple parameter sets, the default interface can work well (especially if your users are more savvy).  But larger and more complicated parameter sets can quickly become overwhelming in the default interface (which can be an even bigger problem if you don't expect your users to be so savvy).

I faced a similar problem with a large set of reports.  Some can be very simple (I.E., no parameters or a simple date range) and some can be hideously overcomplicated (25+ parameters).

The solution that we reached was to write an ASP.NET report menu application which retrieved the Parameters from SSRS for most reports and dynamically presented them to the users.  Some reports were too complicated for this, so we went further and wrote WebUserControls for them which went further in simplifying the parameters for the users.  This way, most Reports didn't require extra intervention, and for those that did, we had the framework for easily creating a wrapper.

Here's an example of how to get the parameters for a given report through the SSRS Web Service:

```
'ReportingService is a reference to the WebService
Dim rs As New ReportingService
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        Dim Reports() As ReportingService.CatalogItem
        Reports = rs.ListChildren(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportPath"), True)

        For Each item As ReportingService.CatalogItem In Reports

            Dim historyID As String = Nothing
            Dim forRendering As Boolean = True
            Dim values As ReportingService.ParameterValue() = Nothing
            Dim credentials As ReportingService.DataSourceCredentials() = Nothing
            Dim params As ReportingService.ReportParameter() = Nothing

            If item.Type = ReportingService.ItemTypeEnum.Report And item.ID = ReportID Then
                params = rs.GetReportParameters(item.Path, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials)
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each param As ReportingService.ReportParameter In params
                    'Display the parameter or add to a collection or whatever
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

You can use the above method to get all of the parameters and then display them as you see fit.  Then all you have to do is collect the results, validate them, and pass them to a ReportViewer.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. I guess the nice thing about the default UI is that it handles common scenarios where parameters cascade.

Comment: @ek_ny You would definitely need to consider that when writing a new UI.  However, doing so opens up even further customizability (of course, at the cost of the time spent to implement new features). The big thing that I felt was missing from the default UI is validation tools.